# What would macroscopic quantum interference look like?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, decoherence

I've heard that the reason we don't see quantum effects at the macroscopic level is because of decoherence.

But I don't know what quantum effects at the macroscopic level would even look like... So I don't understand what exactly decoherence is preventing from happening at the macroscopic level.... what exactly does "interference" mean on the macroscopic level?

As an example, suppose we throw a baseball, and hypothetically suppress decoherence. What exactly would we observe?

EDIT here's a quote from wikipedia:

"Decoherence represents an extremely fast process for macroscopic objects, since these are interacting with many microscopic objects, with an enormous number of degrees of freedom in their natural environment. The process is needed if we are to understand why we tend not to observe quantum behavior in everyday macroscopic objects and why we do see classical fields emerge from the properties of the interaction between matter and radiation for large amounts of matter."

[Quantum decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence#Loss_of_interference_and_the_transition_from_quantum_to_classical_probabilities)

So let's say that decoherence on macroscopic objects was extremely slow? What would we then observe? All these descriptions keep talking about "the reason we don't observe X at the macroscopic level"... but they don't describe what X looks like on the macroscopic level. That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: Probably a more receptive audience here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you ever seen interferences in water waves? Have you ever seen the double slit experiment with light/water?

Comment: @Mauricio, yes... so the baseball would appear like water waves?

Comment: The stability of matter is a macroscopic quantum effect. The magnetic field of a permanent magnet is a macroscopic quantum effect. Superconductivity is a macroscopic quantum effect. All of chemistry is a macroscopic quantum effect. Planck radiation and the photoelectric effect can be demonstrated with nothing but macroscopic equipment. Optical emission and absorption lines are macroscopic quantum effects. Solar panels use quantum effects on a macroscopic scale...

Comment: You appear to be conflating/muddling two separate concepts: quantum effects underlying macroscopic phenomena and the decoupling of the uncertainty principle from classical theories of macroscopic systems. Rephrasing your question to clarify you are only interested in the latter would stanch the urge to perorate on the classical limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am struggling to find a good answer to your questions because fundamentally... decoherence doesn't really prevent quantum mechanics from being the dominant effect on any scale. As I mentioned in my comment almost everything imaginable in the realm of radiation and matter physics is a direct consequence of quantum mechanics. It can not be explained with classical physics at all and it has not been explained with classical physics. What we know as "modern physics", i.e. the application of the theory of relativity and quantum mechanics, presents a revolutionary step in the human understanding of the universe. Before 1900 physicists would just blankly stare at most phenomena, make a table of their measurements and then slide that table into the appropriate section of the library... without any true understanding of what caused it.

The notable exceptions are classical mechanics (particularly celestial mechanics), classical electrodynamics and (classical) thermodynamics.

So, basically... everything you see in the universe is quantum mechanics at work and this pattern is only "broken" by three outliers: systems with large (angular) momentum (classical mechanics), systems with a large number of electromagnetic quanta (classical electrodynamics) and systems with a high temperature (classical thermodynamics). And even these cases still have exceptions, as mentioned. The mere existence of matter that can have "a center of mass" is still a quantum effect. The existence of macroscopic electromagnetic fields is still a quantum effect and quantum effects like Planck radiation that depend on the proper choice of statistics are not going away at any temperature. They are not restricted to a realm below some critical T_c like superconductivity.

So how does "decoherence" create "the classical world"? Well, it doesn't, really. Decoherence, at least in my opinion, is best described as the effect of continuous weak measurement, which is NOT the standard procedure in quantum mechanics where we apply a single measurement to a system with a single quantum of energy or, at most, a very small number of quanta of energy. Instead we pick a system that has a very large amount of energy, momentum, angular momentum and then we keep performing consecutive interactions that add or remove a very small quantity of either of these properties. So instead of looking at an "initial state - final state" one-step, we look at an "initial state, next state, next state, next state...., final state" sequence.

A typical example of this is the Mott problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_problem), which asks how one can explain the tracks of (charged) high energy quanta in a matter filled detector with wave mechanics. In the shortest possible version it's essentially an effect of conditional probabilities: if we "locate" the high energy quantum once by colliding it with a piece of matter, then the scattered quantum (now with a slightly different energy and momentum) will be located the next time close to the first position but it will still have almost the same amount of momentum and energy, i.e. there is a series of momenta vectors of consecutively new quanta that are pointing from detector position to detector position and that are forming an almost straight line.

Why almost straight? Because there will be a momentum uncertainty in the transversal direction after every new position measurement. It is basically a random walk around  a slowing linear motion path.

So what does this look like once all the "kinetic energy" is used up and the position measurements are basically just generating momentum uncertainty around an average momentum of p=0? It looks like a Gaussian random walk... which is the solution of the Schroedinger equation for the free "particle".

Does decoherence ever generate a classical solution? No. It doesn't. If we want to pretend that there is no random walk, either, then we have to make the mass of the system extremely large, limit the measurement precision to some scale above the random walks diffusion length for the given measurement duration and/or use a short time approximation, because in the t->infinity case the random walk aspect will always win out over the coarse graining.

So, in other words... the classical Newtonian solution NEVER appears. WE just don't care to measure long enough to observe that it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful, especially the reference to the Mott problem.